# Caching the fact that a resource does not exist

Tags: java, memcached

Had an issue where something could not be cached that effected the load on our system.

Because of a bug, my code was calling a service with incorrect parameters and that service of course returned a 404, null, empty. Basically, nothing was found to satisfy the request. The fact that nothing was found was returned to a procedure that was caching the response. My caching system does not allow us to cache the value null so we basically could not cache the response or the fact that there was no response and therefor we had to make a live call every time this scenario happened. Because of the bug it happened a lot.

I have of course fixed the bug, but my question is whether or not there is and/or should be a way to cache the fact that some resource could not be found. If we could have had such a safety net in place the bug would not have been as severe.

Should there be a way to cache the fact that something is not found or not? Why or why not?

I am using memcache servers with a spymemcached client and my code is written in Java, though my question should be agnostic to that fact. Perhaps other implementations could provide a cacheKey exists method or something like that. I have researched this and haven't found anything in the Java world that I think is adequate for my situation. Even if there were I might not be able to switch to it because of company standards.

Comment: Your question pertains to `memcache`, not Java, as you point out.  So why research "in the Java world"?

Comment: You caught me. I am curious how non-java implementations might handle this situation, but in the end I am researching the java solution because that is what I will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to know whether or not a value exists, and null is a valid value, I would typically use a "holder" or "singleton" class.  For example:

```
public final class Singleton<T> {
  private final T value;
  public Singleton(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  private final T get() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

So now instead of:

```
// if this returns null, does it mean the document doesn't exist 
// or there's nothing in the cache?
public Document getCached(String name);
```

You can use:

```
// if this returns null, there's nothing in the cache
// if non-null, the singleton wrapper may contain a null value,
// indicating the document doesn't exist
public Singleton<Document> getCached(String name);
```

Comment: Interesting idea. This would definitely work and I don't think it would be a huge performance hit. It would be nice if there was some built in functionality, but this would definitely be a work around for the lack of that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define a constant value which *represents* null?  Then cache that, and account for it on read.

Comment: That actually is an option that I have considered. The only problem is that the implementation I use returns an Object instance that needs to be cast to the object I use. If I have some kind of default value then I will have to check every single time I pull an object out of memcache to see whether or not it is that default object. This would work, but it might be kind of a performance hit for a situation that rarely happens. Maybe it is a performance hit any way that I look at it. I will mark this answer as the accepted answer if I don't get a better alternative.